# Excel Vba to loop through cells of rows of columns

Tags: vba, excel

Could you assist me with the following; I can't find anything relevant to what I want..
I m looking for VBa code that once a user has completed a line (of a table for example) check if all the cells across the different columns (of the static table) have been completed and if not throw a msgbox.

So I a user was to complete on or more rows of the table, the code would check if all the info has been inserted.
In case, this doesn't make any sense I can draw it somehow.
Any help would be appreciated!thanks

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). SO is not a code-server where you place orders for code/methods to do something. It is here to help you write your own code.

Comment: I have to say this seems like a perfectly reasonable question. If SO isn't a place where you can ask how to code something and/or see previous Qs and the answers that might be relevant to what you are trying to do, then I have no idea why you would want to come here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
       Dim rng As Range, i As Integer, j As Integer
   Set rng = Range("A1:B4")
   For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
      For j = 1 to rng.Columns.count
         If rng(i, j) = "" Then
            MsgBox "Not all the cells have been filled out"
            Exit For
         End If
      Next
    Next
```

Comment: That's it thank you. I changed it a bit but that seems to have worked. Thanks